# php scrape dynamically loaded content via ajax using knockout.js

Tags: php, ajax, knockout.js

I need to scrape some data from a website which is being loaded via ajax using knockout.js (I don't know exactly on which technology it is working.)

Site is **www.msc.com**. Here I am searching for schedules like from Barcelona to Miami. So the result is loaded via ajax but doesn't show up in console or firebug.

I have tried too many times. Any help or suggestion will be appreciable.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what DATA you're aiming for? If I open my console under the NETWORK tab, I can see PORTS is returned using a JSON object.  Give us an exact route of what to type in in what URL and what you expect to obtain please.

Comment: Oh sorry. When we search a schedule like port of load and port of discharge. Ex. Port of load : Barcelona and port of discharge : Miami. We will get all the ships details loaded below. I want that content to be scraped.

Answer (score 0):

Their script is located at: https://www.msc.com/CMSTemplates/CraftedCMS/WebServices/RouteFinder.svc/Routes

They prevent you from calling it directly in a browser tab/window, probably because what you're trying to do is against their policy.  If they wanted people to scrape their DATA, they would not block direct requests to their API or they would provide another publicly documented API for you to use on your server.

With that said, you can see in your browser console that their web service returns JSON objects.  You will have to hack (maybe illegally) your way by faking protocol variables in order to accomplish what you're aiming for.  The first things to consider is that they only return results through that web service when:

a) The call is made through XMLHttpRequest as POST.  (This you can fake it easily, but the next points, not so much...)

b) The call is made using a referer, in this precise case, the referer is: https://www.msc.com/routefinder?fromId=406&isCountryFrom=false&toId=83&isCountryTo=false

c) The call passes a cookie to the server, which is encrypted and signed, so each session is in their database and your key is probably unique, so good luck decrypting this: CMSPreferredCulture=fr-FR; ASP.NET_SessionId=gza5rfjrog2eb21ukrzma223; BIGipServerkentico.app~kentico_pool=439883018.20480.0000; bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb=LIKIGEACDJHDJPGPEOKGJBKODKDGOMHNKAEGEGKNODEDAEILEICBMLNLEFMAOIPPKMOIBBFAILFEEKJPIJDCBDDLFNBBMBPBGGKAIDOCMGHBEEIDMLPMIJJAMNFNIFMI; rxVisitor=1497537754979PTPODMSFNIR8BFVAKK353FS76M2D1KNN; dtPC=3$537845860_975h-vCQTABPJMGEOKDPDVNLHPCPDASGAPMCPCBA; rxvt=1497539656937|1497537754995; dtSa=-; dtLatC=8; _ga=GA1.2.1247106544.1497537756; _gid=GA1.2.879601947.1497537756; _gali=results; cookiePolicyApproved=true; MSCAgencyId=355840; _gat=1; _gat_local=1; dtCookie=3$B74DFC30736F7DBF485B79C31C55B167|www.msc.com|1

[image: JSON Object returned by their website routes API]